# Make the batch file wait for another batch file

Tags: batch-file

How to make the batch file wait for the first line of command (which executes another batch file) before going to the second line?

When the batch file executes the first line of command, the execution takes time. But the batch file goes to the second line of command without waiting for the first line to finish.

```
@echo off

"MyOtherBatFile1.bat" "MyArgs1"

echo wait until above batch file is fully executed.

"MyOtherBatFile2.bat" "MyArgs2"
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Call` to start the MyOtherBatFile*.bat batchfiles. See `call /?` for the correct syntax.